# Modify new collection without touching the original one

Tags: c#, generics, collections, deep-copy

My goal is to get a copy of collection with specified item removed from it without touching the items of original collection. I have the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the operation I am doing is:

```
 var collection = new Collection<Foo>
                         {
                             new Foo {Name = "Name1"},
                             new Foo {Name = "Name2"},
                             new Foo {Name = "Name3"},
                             new Foo {Name = "Name4"}
                         };
    var newCollection = new Collection<Foo>(collection);

    Foo f = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Name2");
    if (f != null)
    {
        newCollection.Remove(f);
    }
```

i.e I am removing the item from "newCollection" but the issue is that the following line:

```
newCollection.Remove(f);
```

is removing the item from original collection too i.e from "collection" object. I want to modify "newCollection" only and not "collection". How can I do that? Isn't the following line doing a deep copy:

```
 var newCollection = new Collection<Foo>(collection);
```

if so, then why the original object is affected?

I know I can achieve my goal via this line too:

```
var newCollection = collection.Where(x => x.Name != "Name2");
```

but I am in dilemma about the Remove stuff and deep copy stuff happening above.

Comment: It is the System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the behaviour of the [`Collection<T>(IList<T>)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132401.aspx):

> The elements of the list are not copied. The list is wrapped by the collection, so that subsequent changes to the elements of the list are visible through the Collection.

If you want a shallow copy of the collection<sup>1</sup>, you could use `List<T>` instead:

```
List<Foo> newCollection = new List<T>(collection);
```

(It's a little odd to see `Collection<T>` used like this at all. It's normally used as the *base* class for other generic collections.)

---

<sup>1</sup> It's a shallow copy because it's just copying the value of each element as a reference, rather than cloning each `Foo` object. If you wrote:

```
newCollection[0].Name = "Hello!";
Console.WriteLine(collection[0]);
```

... it would still print "Hello!". Creating a wrapper around an existing collection isn't really creating a copy at all, shallow *or* deep.

Comment: You mean a deep copy via this "new List(collection);", Right? and not the shallow copy which I assume was a typo in your reply.

Comment: @RockySingh: No, I mean a shallow copy. A deep copy would clone each element. A shallow copy just copies the *references* - but still creates an independent collection. I've edited my answer to provide a footnote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone it, the newCollection is only a reference to the original collection.

Comment: What about this line then "var newCollection = new Collection<Foo>(collection);"

Comment: @RockySingh: See my answer - and the documentation.

Comment: see my answer , see my answer! Jon, why are you such an attention ****?

Answer (score 0):

`Collection<Foo>(collection)` wrapps only the provided collection, so that any changes to the collection also effect the original collection.

You should use a `List<Foo>` to do what you want, cause constructor of `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` copies the values from the original collection.

```
var collection = new Collection<Foo>
                         {
                             new Foo {Name = "Name1"},
                             new Foo {Name = "Name2"},
                             new Foo {Name = "Name3"},
                             new Foo {Name = "Name4"}
                         };
    var newCollection = new List<Foo>(collection);

    Foo f = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Name2");
    if (f != null)
    {
        newCollection.Remove(f);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this instead.

```
  var newCollection = new Collection<Foo>();

collection.ToList().ForEach(x => newCollection.Add(x));
```